# Is it Advisable to have multiple services injecting in to a Single Class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have around 10-15 sequential API calls to be performed to complete an operation.

Each API, has its own separate service implementation classes to get its corresponding response. To process all these API, I autowired all these 15 classes in to a single class and executing one by one.

By looking at the code, i feel the approach is not a decent way for this implementation.

Could you please suggest whether this is fine to go or any other way to beautify the implementation?

My implementation is:
I perform booking operation which has 15 services to be called sequentially. Based on each service's success response, the chain will continue to the next one. In this case, I injected all those 15 services in my `BookingServiceImpl` using `@Autowired`. So, my implementation is correct right? Any other better approach than this?

Comment: It is hard to give you an answer while not knowing what exactly your software does. However, when I had to perform this kind of computations I always use the Chain Of Responsibility pattern.

Comment: I use the same chain of responsibility pattern. But, the class where you are implementing it, if each chain requires an API call, then you have to autowire all the 15 services in to a single class right? Is that good?

Comment: Combine your COR with command pattern. In this way you can autowire in a List all bean implementing the same interface.

Comment: Autowiring as many components, services, repositories into a single class could or could not be a problem. It might be an indicative of a bad design or it could be needed. It's hard to tell without seeing a code sample. From what you define, if that single class needs that 15 calls/services to do it's job, then it might be needed.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral, Yes. My single class required all the 15 services. I perform booking operation which has 15 services to be called sequentially. Based on each service's success response, the chain will continue to the next one. In this case, i injected all those 15 services in my BookingServiceImpl using autowired. So, my implementation is correct right? Any other better approach than this?

Comment: Yes - you could model these as plugin chain [Chain of responsibility] with a sequence of plugins each solving a particular API call problem.

Comment: I repeat that it is very hard to say anything without seeing any code or sample. With just that information, I don't see a problem.

Comment: could you give me a few service names so I can refer to them in my answer? I need to know several steps in processing a booking

Comment: @HasanCanSaral it's not that hard. 15 dependencies gathered in one place clearly indicate design flaws

Comment: I would argue that there might be a case where it might be needed, even if that would be a long shot. But you are right.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, My booking service processes are like, 1.fetchBookingSourceDataByID(this will have complete info like custInfo, orderInfo, paymentInfo,etc), 2.validateCustomerInfo, 3.addCustomer(if the customer is not exists. will be knowing from the step 2 api call), 4.paymentProcessing, 5.customerOrderMapping, etc. All these has to be performed one by one once Booking is initiated. If any error in between of any service, that's not a prob. I've handled it.

Comment: @Shakthi I added my answer, what do you think?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, Yes this looks good. Thank you so much for the suggestion. The purpose of I @autowired all the services is, if it fails in `CustomerValidationService` while I reprocess it, I have to start from `CustomerValidationService` only. In your example, its not directly possible right? We may pass some reference to skip some services and have to start the actual service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not right in any way.

A class that relies on 15 dependencies is never well-designed and violates [the single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). A system where such class resides can be called [tightly coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).

Although [the chain of responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) brings more abstraction and complexity, it may significantly improve the current design. The components may be well decoupled, each performing a single piece of work and being unaware of the whole process. There may be no single class controlling the entire procedure. You may make Spring responsible for the order in the chain, which would become a dynamically rearranged and reconfigured entity at runtime.

I will give you a very abstract snippet, the direction I would follow:

```
interface Booking {
    // methods required at any stage of processing
}

interface BookingProcessor {
    void process(Booking booking);
}

@Service("BookingSourceDataService")
class BookingSourceDataService implements BookingProcessor {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("CustomerValidationService")
    private BookingProcessor nextProcessor;

    @Override
    public void process(Booking booking) {
        // fetch booking source data, populate the Booking object
        nextProcessor.process(booking);
    }

}
@Service("CustomerValidationService")
class CustomerValidationService implements BookingProcessor {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("CustomerCreationService")
    private BookingProcessor nextProcessor;

    @Override
    public void process(Booking booking) {
        // validate customer, populate the Booking object
        nextProcessor.process(booking);
    }

}
```

Note how Spring and its meta-information can decrease the level of coupling. For instance, `BookingSourceDataService` has no idea what its next booking processor is.